# This linq query is going out of index after the Visual studio update

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linq

```
var temp = this.ObjectContext.ActiveDepViews
    .Where(p => p.id== id)
    .Join(this.ObjectContext.Departments.Where(p => p.ida == ida),
        p => p.Id, q => q.Id,
        (p, q) => new { ActiveDepViews = p})
    .Select(p => p.ActiveDepViews)
    .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
    .ToList();
```

This query was working up until I updated Visual Studio. Now it's giving me an index out of bound error.

I checked the data and it's all there — it doesn't make any sense.

Can anyone tell me how to revert my update on Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: This isn't anything to do with a Visual Studio update, I can all but guarantee that.  What's the precise error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linq has an error here ,I am surprised that you can build this linq

Try this, this should work :

```
var temp = this.ObjectContext.ActiveDepViews.Where(p => p.id== id)
        .Join(this.ObjectContext.Departments.Where(p => p.ida== ida),
        p => p.Id, q => q.Id, (p, q) => new { ActiveDepViews = p, Departments = q})
        .Select(p => p.ActiveDepViews).OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I cant belive this little error caused my linq to break. But why was it working before the VS update then?

Comment: why is that not a syntax error.. shouldn't the compiler catch the error ?